# Show only one record, if value same in another column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, duplicates

I have a table with 5 columns like this:

```
 | ID | NAME  | PO_NUMBER  | DATE       | STATS |
 | 1  | Jhon  | 160101-001 | 2016-01-01 | 7     |
 | 2  | Jhon  | 160101-002 | 2016-01-01 | 7     |
 | 3  | Jhon  | 160102-001 | 2016-01-02 | 7     |
 | 4  | Jane  | 160101-001 | 2016-01-01 | 7     |
 | 5  | Jane  | 160102-001 | 2016-01-02 | 7     |
 | 6  | Jane  | 160102-002 | 2016-01-02 | 7     |
 | 7  | Jane  | 160102-003 | 2016-01-02 | 7     |
```

I need to display all values, but `stats` fields without duplicate according from `date` field.
Like this

```
 | ID | NAME  | PO_NUMBER  | DATE       | STATS |
 | 1  | Jhon  | 160101-001 | 2016-01-01 | 7     |
 | 2  | Jhon  | 160101-002 | 2016-01-01 | null  |
 | 3  | Jhon  | 160102-001 | 2016-01-02 | 7     |
 | 4  | Jane  | 160101-001 | 2016-01-01 | 7     |
 | 5  | Jane  | 160102-001 | 2016-01-02 | 7     |
 | 6  | Jane  | 160102-002 | 2016-01-02 | null  |
 | 7  | Jane  | 160102-003 | 2016-01-02 | null  |
```

I've had trouble getting the hoped. Thanks

Comment: example date 2016-01-01 is three time repeated  is example correct ..

Comment: what version of `SQL Server` are you using ?

Comment: @sandeeprawat yes, date field is repeated value

Comment: @Squirrel sql server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your sample data, it appears you only want to show the `stats` for `po_number` ending with `001`.  If so, this should be the easiest approach:

```
select id, name, po_number, date, 
       case when right(po_number, 3) = '001' then stats else null end as stats
from yourtable
```

---

If instead you want to `order by` the `po_number`, then here's one option using `row_number`:

```
select id, name, po_number, date, 
       case when rn = 1 then stats else null end as stats
from (
     select *, row_number() over (partition by name, date order by po_number) as rn
     from yourtable
) t
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cc259/2)

Comment: Yes, in example this `po_number` have ending same 001. But i've to show according from `date`, isn't possible?

Comment: @Ricky -- the second example does just that.  see this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cc259/2

Comment: Thanks @sgeddes, I am very grateful to you

Answer (score 0):

since you are using SQL 2012, you can use the LEAD() or LAG() window function to compare the DATE value

```
select  *,
        STATS = case when t.DATE = LAG(DATE) OVER(ORDER BY ID) 
                     then NULL 
                     else STATS 
                     end
from    yourtable t
```

Comment: I also thought about this, but I don't think it will handle more than 2 in a group.

Comment: what do you mean by `more than 2 in a group` ? Example ?

Comment: Thanks also @Squirrel was help my problem, in local i.ve used sql 2012 but i dont know in server using

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
  ;with temp as (
            select id,name ,PO_NUMBER ,DATE, STATS,
            LAG (STATS, 1, 0) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY name ,PO_NUMBER ,DATE ORDER BY id) AS PrevSTATS  
            from tableName 
    )
       select id,name ,PO_NUMBER ,DATE,
        case when  STATS = PrevSTATS then null 
               else     STATS end as STATS  
    from temp
```